# How to change Alt + B Passpartout Bounding Box Color

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, customization

We can hide the geometry of a mesh/object basically edit and object mode by clipping it with a bounding box using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> hotkey. Yet, I really find this clipped space a bit distracting when modelling:
[image]
I basically want this to be the same color as the viewport, not something a bit darker, is there a way/setting to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Themes* > *3D Viewport* and set the color for *Clipping Border* to your liking.

If you use the *Eyedropper* tool in the color settings you should normally get the original background color by clicking on it, but for me it looks a little brighter. So maybe you have to adjust it manually.

Comment: Seems a bit tricky to get the right color. In Photoshop my background has a HEX value of 3C3C3C, which is what the color picker sets for the clipping border if I click on the background. But to get those colors to look like the same, I have to set the clipping border to 393939. Looks like Blender uses different colorspaces in the preferences and the viewport.